# node.js struct serialization for c++ addon

Tags: c++, node.js, serialization

I am developing my first web app with a node.js/c++ backend. The compute-intensive part of my application will be done in a c++ class and included in node.js via an addon.

My problem is that the c++ functions need a complicated nested struct (thousands of bytes) as input. I thought of creating a buffer (new Uint8Array()) and passing it to the c++ addon, but I see no good way for populating the buffer in node.js -- the byte offset for each nested member will need to be known in the javascript.

Any suggestions? The needed data for the struct comes from forms. C++ needs the data as a complicated struct. I plan to store the data in a database as well later, not in buffer format.

Comment: Package your data into a string and send that to your C++ code.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30044724/json-stringify-versus-serialization) that has some good info in the answers.

Comment: using JSON seems quite horrible to me unless it can't be avoided. I am dealing with numeric data. Converting to and from strings would be a huge waste. Furthermore, I want to access the data in-place in my cpp without copying and any preprocessing.